# What is the best way to add class library in C# project?

Tags: c#, dll, class-library

I have a project and I have created a custom class library for this project.

Now, my problem is I know how I can add a reference of the custom library and add its .dll. But, whenever I'll try to make any change in the library, I'll make changes and then recompile it and then, add its reference again in the project. How can I avoid this tedious process?

Comment: The projects (the library and its client), they are not in the same Visual Studio solution?

Comment: You have one solution that contains one project.  You prefer two.

Comment: No  @Marlonchosky Because I want to add that library in two projects

Comment: like the @Martheen's answer said, you can add your library project in the solution (or solutions) where the client project is. Then, add a project to project reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use [project to project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019#project-to-project-references) references. If they're not in the same solution, you can add an existing project to a solution (File-Add-Existing Project).